# Vertically center Inline Block Modal Dialog

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to vertically center a `modal-dialog` which has `display: inline-block` in order to change the width of the modal based on the content. I centered the modal horizontally with `text-align: center` on `modal`, this does not center it vertically though. How do I go about centering it vertically?

```css
.modal {
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-dialog {
     max-width: 100%;
     width: auto !important;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade modal-xl" id="pictureModal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header border-0 text-light">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close " data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vertically align it to what? Do you mean center vertically? That's not what vertical align does.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the easiest to pass `modal-dialog-center` next to `modal-dialog` class (as per bootstrap docs). Your display type shouldn't affect vertical centering

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#vertically-centered

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: @Patroick You can also set the position of the modal class to fixed and then position absolute on modal-dialog. The last step would be to apply transform: translateY(-50%) to modal-dialog. That's not very elegant but should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using flexbox. This code will center the modal content vertically -

```
.modal {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```